# what is the best way to refresh access token with refresh token using jwt in mongo - realm - flutter web

Tags: mongodb, flutter, jwt, realm

i got jwt from firebase auth with : `await firebaseUser.getIdToken();` , the reason is, i use google sign via pop up, but use mongo with their fancy realm.

then i use firebase jwt to login user to mongo with via http post : `api/client/v2.0/app/$appId/auth/providers/$providerType/login` , and they return access, refresh token, and id as bonus :

```
{
 "access_token" : "<value>",
 "refresh_token": "<value>",
 "user_id: "<id>"
}
```

now i can make http endpoint function call, but the problem is, based on their [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/users/sessions/#std-label-manage-user-sessions),

> Access tokens expire 30 minutes after they are granted. When an access
> token expires, you must get a new access token to continue sending
> requests.

I understand its mandatory purpose to protect data, i read some our community suggest in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69773122/15366030) the idea is :

> renewing process can be happing in the background (maybe using
> workers)

what is the proper way to refresh this token? should i call this api `curl -X POST 'https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/auth/session' \ --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \ --header 'Authorization: Bearer <RefreshToken>'` to refresh it every 30 minutes using scheduler, or should i check if token not expired on every http method request? or there is any better way to do this on flutter web? i need help and guide thank you in advance

Comment: Are you only using Firebase for Authentication? Why not use [fancy Realm Flutter Google Auth](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/users/authenticate/#google-user) to simplify and streamline the process?

Comment: @jay yes sir, but their flutter sdk [dont support for web](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/flutter/install/#supported-platforms)

Comment: Ah ok - to be clear, you are NOT using Realm Flutter SDK.